# Parentheses immediately after a reference in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've found that the following type of formula is valid to enter in Excel:
`=A1(2,3)`, or in general using some named range (`NamedRange`) and cell references, that this is valid:

`=NamedRange(A2,A3,A4)`.

However each of these gives me a `#REF!` error, and I would like to know how this operation should work in Excel?
(The closest I could find would be the intersect (space) operator:

`=NamedRange (A2,A3,A4)`

which would work.)

Thank you for your help, I'm asking because I've seen this formula in a sheet, and would like to know the intent of how this should be working - any example of using this which doesn't return `#REF!` would be extremely useful.

Comment: What are these used for and what is your specific programming question?

Comment: Are you sure its a named range and not User Defined Function (UDF) in vba?

Comment: Thank you @ForwardEd, I've looked quite a lot at this workbook, and do think that the only way this could work would be as a UDF (even though this workbook is using an external Named Range). I think that this must be an error, and would only ever be returning `#REF!`. I'll post a more structured reply in the answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at the workbook in more detail, and considering Forward Ed's comment above, I hope to provide some explanation of what I think is the cause of the errors I was seeing in my question above:

In Excel, I think that brackets outside of text are *only* used as an operator:

- to group ranges: `(A1, B2, C3)`
- As a function call `SUM(_args_)`

In this case, because there is no space before the brackets, this indicates that what comes before must be a function (this can be seen in Excel's formula editor, which shows an unknown function `NamedRange` with the arguments inside.

It it possible to have this for an external reference from an XLA (Excel Add-In) sheet containing a VBA function, which would act in this way. I.e. if the VBA function were called `Foo`, then it could be called from the referencing workbook as `Foo(A1,B2)`, for example.

This wasn't the case in my example, as I was able to view the saved reference in the Excel workbook, and it showed that the `NamedRange` in the external XLA file was indeed a cell reference directly to a cell `$A$23` which contains a boolean. However, I think this was a mistake by the last person to save the file, and that probably this reference should be (and would only return a result) for some user-defined-function (UDF) in VBA.

I think this answers the question about why the formula `=NamedRange(A2,A3,A4)` is valid, even though as a named range it will always return `#REF!`, and that is because, Excel will need to handle formulas of this type *in the specific case* where the reference is actually to a user-defined-function.

(This is in contrast to a function like `=NamedRange(A1,SUM(` which Excel will stop a user from entering with a warning that the formula is invalid. This is because no such formula with this syntax could ever be valid).